# onchange input value trigger select option change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#delivery_date").change(function(){
    jQuery("#shipping_method_0").trigger('change');
  });
});
```

If a user clicks on the input, the Select option automatically refreshes.

Comment: *automatically refreshes* What does this mean? Please share a working snippet using `<>` demonstrating your attempt and issue.

Comment: above code working properly in desktop, if u check in mobile code not working.

Comment: Post a fiddle pls

Comment: https://www.dpsainiflorist.com/checkout/

Comment: check shipping time

Comment: if u change shipping date left side of bottom on checkout page once u change date, all shipping time will show on right side of shipping option

Comment: website url
https://www.dpsainiflorist.com/checkout/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1b9u5Lw1/

Comment: pls someone help me

Comment: @SaurabhKapoor Debug your website, it is full of errors

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on mobile and the below convention solved it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#delivery_date").on('change', function(){
    jQuery("#shipping_method_0").trigger('change');
  });
});
```

and for `change` event in `shipping_method_0` follow the same structure.

```
jQuery("#shipping_method_0").on('change', function(){
    //code goes here
});
```

Comment: This has exact same behaviour than OP's posted code  https://api.jquery.com/change/#entry-longdesc